# Is there any solution to use podman with spring boot docker compose support?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, podman

I'm trying to adjust my project to take advantage of spring boot support for docker compose, but I have some problems using podman, instead of docker.

Spring Boot uses ProcessBuilder to do the Docker command checks inside the DockerCli class, but ProcessBuilder doesn't take into account the defined 'aliases' when it runs the docker command:

```
alias docker=podman
```

So, when I run the application I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerProcessStartException: Unable to start docker process. Is docker correctly installed?
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli$DockerCommands.getDockerCommand(DockerCli.java:140) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli$DockerCommands.<init>(DockerCli.java:129) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.lambda$new$0(DockerCli.java:65) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1228) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.<init>(DockerCli.java:64) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCompose.get(DockerCompose.java:92) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.getDockerCompose(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:147) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:110) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:416) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.github.kai9026.bootupdates.SpringBootUpdatesApplication.main(SpringBootUpdatesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessStartException: Unable to start command docker version --format {{.Client.Version}}
```

Is there any solution to use podman with spring boot docker compose support without having to install docker? I tried different things but I have not been able to get it to work.

Regards.

Comment: An `alias` will usually only apply to the shell you define it in, it is *not* inherited by other process, especially not ones that don't themselves use/call a shell. So try to create a symlink somewhere on the path instead of defining an `alias`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @joachim-sauer. The truth is that I had not thought of such a solution until you mentioned it to me. Thanks again.